# Nexus 4 - Bootloop after screen replacement

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, nexus-4, data-recovery, boot-loop

I've replaced a screen on a Nexus 4, and now I can't turn it on, it goes into *bootloop*. I can enter recovery mode, and even tried to wipe cache partition but it didn't help. One more detail, I'm trying to turn it on without backcover, because I'm going to replace digitazer, don't sure can it affect in such way my phone or not. Before I replaced the screen, everything worked fine.

My big problem is that I haven't done backup before performing this maintenance and therefore I don't want to do the *hard reset*. Can I in some way to make a backup of my phone right now or cause it to work?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found what was a problem thanks to that thread : [Nexus 4 Stuck at boot screen after replacing the LCD/Digitizer](http://forums.androidcentral.com/general-help-how/382194-nexus-4-stuck-boot-screen-after-replacing-lcd-digitizer.html), I've forgotten to attach the headphone connector, after I've done it, it begun to work.

Comment: If you have answered your own question to your satisfaction, you should mark it as the correct answer for future readers.